# assignment makes integer from pointer without cast in C

Tags: c, database, closures, relational-database

I have a project in my DATABASES class, the teacher asked us to create a program that calculates the CLOSURE of a relation based on an attribute. 
I typed the first part of the function that calculates the Closure but the compiler keeps giving this warning :

```
warning : assignment makes integer from pointer without cast
```

here is the function and the structure that goes with it:

```
typedef struct df {
    char PG[20];
    char PD[20];
} DF;
char *Closure(DF *T, char *C, int sizeFD, char att, int n) {
    int i, j;
    j = 0;
    C[j] = att;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeFD; i++) {
        if (T[i].PG == &att) {
            j++;
            C[j] = T[i].PD;  // this is where there's the warning
        }
    }
    if (j == n)
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return C;
}
```

I need your help, please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending statement is:

```
C[j] = T[i].PD;
```

`C` is a `char *`, hence `C[j]` is a `char` and cannot be assigned `T[i].PD`, which is an array and *decays* as a pointer to `char` .

Note that `T[i].PG == &att` is always false because `att` is a local variable and `T[i].PG` is an array inside a structure.

It is unclear what the code is attempting to do.

Comment: the first loop in the code is supposed to go over all the functional dependencies entered before ( in other functions) and compare if the right part of the functional dependencies are equal to the attribute tha we wish to calculate it's closure, if you want i can post the whole code , so it may clear up for you.

Comment: @YvonneStyles Posting the whole code may not be advisable, depending on how much code that is. Posting a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be best (emphasis on Minimal).

Answer (score 0):

```
C[j]=T[i].PD;
```

Let's break this down.  First C is of type char* and

```
C[j] ==> *(C + j) // type char
```

Meaning that you are writing the value of the location of C + j.

Next T[i].PD is a char* but C[j] is of type char.

Now C is a bit of a weird language because it handles the casting of these types and treats T[i].PD as an integer.  To C everything is bits underneath and it trusts you know the relationship between types.

Comment: More precisely: `T[i].PD` is **not** a `char*`, it is an array of `char`, assigning it stores the address of the first byte of the array into the lvalue, which is not a `char*`.